# Can someone explain the calculus within this gradient descent function?

Tags: derivatives, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm new to calculus and I was convinced that what is happening in the gradient descent function is not calculus. It turns out that it is, can someone explain how? Where is the derivative being computed?

```
import os
import sys 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sympy import *
from numpy.linalg import inv
import random
#sizes = [2104,1416,1534,852]
#prices = [460,232,315,178]

path = os.getcwd() + '\data\ex1data1.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, names=['Population', 'Profit'])

# append a ones column to the front of the data set
data.insert(0, 'Ones', 1)

# set X (training data) and y (target variable) 
cols = data.shape[1]  
X = data.iloc[:,0:cols-1]  
y = data.iloc[:,cols-1:cols] 

X = np.matrix(X.values)  
y = np.matrix(y.values) 

print X,y  
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))

def computeCost(X, y, theta):  
    inner = np.power(((X * theta.T) - y), 2)
    return np.sum(inner) / (2 * len(X))

def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters):  
    temp_theta = np.matrix(np.zeros(theta.shape))
    num_parameters = int(theta.ravel().shape[1])
    cost = np.zeros(iters)

    for i in range(iters):
        error = (X * theta.T) - y
        for j in range(num_parameters):
            error_term = np.multiply(error, X[:,j])
            temp_theta[0,j] = theta[0,j] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(error_term))

        theta = temp_theta
        cost[i] = computeCost(X, y, theta)

    return theta, cost

# initialize variables for learning rate and iterations
alpha = 0.01  
iters = 1000

# perform gradient descent to "fit" the model parameters
g, cost = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters)  

print g

x = np.linspace(data.Population.min(), data.Population.max(), 100)  
f = g[0, 0] + (g[0, 1] * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))  
ax.plot(x, f, 'r', label='Prediction')  
ax.scatter(data.Population, data.Profit, label='Traning Data')  
ax.legend(loc=2)  
ax.set_xlabel('Population')  
ax.set_ylabel('Profit')  
ax.set_title('Predicted Profit vs. Population Size')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Gradient is a vector of partial derivatives by definition

Comment: The gradient is being computed in the for loop inside the gradient descent function. This code assumes a particular form of the cost function and just hardcodes the derivative accordingly. In general the keyword you want is "backpropagation."

Comment: Mercy please! Spare us the wall of code! $\ddot\frown$

Comment: @Lord Shark: why? It's a mathematical question about what kind of mathematics is happening in some code. The code needs to be there because it's what the OP is confused about.